# How to make Peer to Peer connection in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, voip

I want to implement a Voip app for iPhone.

How could i make peer to peer connection between users using socket programming with streaming.

Any source code available.

Answer (score 1):

try GCDAsyncSocket 
https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket

or you can try this also
http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server

Answer (score 0):

define class properties:

```
NSInputStream *inputStream;
NSOutputStream *outputStream;
```

initialize your streams

```
CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;

CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)kScannerIP, kScannerPort, &readStream, &writeStream);
inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;
outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

[inputStream setDelegate:self];
[outputStream setDelegate:self];

[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

[inputStream open];
[outputStream open];
```

implement delegate method to handle incoming data:

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {
    switch (streamEvent) {
        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
            break;

        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
            break;

        case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:
            break;

        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
            break;

        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
            break;

        default:
            NSLog(@"Unknown event");
    }
}
```

finally close your network:

```
[inputStream close];
[outputStream close];
[inputStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
inputStream = nil;
outputStream = nil;
```

Comment: @
visualication your approach needs to connect with Host and port. My question is "how to connect to particular user using my app on another iPhone?" I mean how to get Host and Port for that user?

Comment: via your own server which knows the users and his ip. in this case your user would be the host. you must keep track of the users and their ips. or you want to do that  with static ips? thats not possible i think...

Answer (score -2):

You can't; what would happen when both of your device's IP change (both moved to a different network)?

Comment: you can with a central server

Comment: Of course, but then it's not peer-to-peer, it's two server-client connections.

Comment: not if the server serve only to dispatch user address and then they can peer to peer

Comment: Yes, but then question should start with something like "Assuming in my client-server architecture I was able to communicate IP address to an iOS device, and using only POSIX calls, how to ...". Because the answer to the question will be different in different cases (there's CFNetworking if this code will be used only in Objective-C and POSIX calls for portability).